# Knockout is slow when unchecking checkboxes on a large (1000) dataset

Tags: javascript, performance, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am using this code, to check all checkboxes on my view.

```
var checked = self.includeAllInSoundscript();
var contents = self.filterContents(self.getFilters());
for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
   contents[i].includeInSoundscript(checked);
}
return true;
```

The checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: includeInSoundscript" title="sometitle" />
```

This is what contents is:

```
(function (ko) {
ContentViewModel = function (data) {
    this.orderId = data.orderId;
    this.contentReferenceId = ko.observable(data.contentReferenceId);
    this.includeInSoundscript = ko.observable();
});
```

This is the filter methods:

```
self.getFilters = function() {
  var filterOrders = $.grep(self.orders(), function (order) {
    return (order.usedInfilter());
  });
  var filterLocations = $.grep(self.locations(), function (location)      {
    return (location.usedInfilter());
  });
  return { orders: filterOrders, locations: filterLocations };
};
self.filterContents = function (filter) {
  var filteredArray = self.contents();
  if (filter.orders.length > 0) {
      filteredArray = $.grep(filteredArray, function (content) {
        return $.grep(filter.orders, function (order) {
          return (order.orderId == content.orderId);
        }).length > 0;
      });
  }
  if (filter.locations.length > 0) {
      filteredArray = $.grep(filteredArray, function (content) {
                         return $.grep(filter.locations, function (location) {
                           return $.inArray(location.location, content.orderedFrom().split('/')) != -1;
  }).length > 0;
});
}
 return filteredArray;
};
```

Checking all checkboxes is fast, but when i uncheck, it can take up to 20 seconds. Strange thing is when the filetered result is small, it still takes a bit longer, even if the filtered results is about 40, from a total set of 1000.

The checkbox is in a table, bound using data-bind="foreach: contents"

I have now removed some of the "unescessary" observables, for properties that most likely will not change, it then behaves slightly better, but still very slow, especially in firefox. The big question is, why is this behavior only on unchecking checkboxes, and not on filtering, sorting, checking, etc.

Notice: Its only unchecking the checkboxes, basically when "checked" is false, otherwise its fast.

Edit: I am only displaying 50 items at a time, but i am checking / unchecking all the filtered items. This, so that I have controll over what to post to the server.

Comment: What is `contents` and `includeInSoundscript`?
How they look?

Comment: It looks like this `contents` generation might be slow. Show us `.filterContents` and `.getFilters` methods.

Comment: Added the code, the content generation for the foreach loop is fast, in fact, everything is pretty fast. Except for unchecking the checkboxes, im using the filter method in other places as well, and it usually takes less than half a second to filter and generate the content. So, I dont really suspect the filter methods to be at fault, I might be wrong though. 

I have also added alerts after the filter code, and before the uncheck code, and the filtering is done really quick, then the uncheck happens, and it slows down.....

Comment: Have you found a solution to the problem? If so, please share it.

Comment: Havent found a solution yet, been busy wither other things, looking at this again today. Will share when i find something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I use for this scenario. Maybe it will help you.

The `checked` binding can work with an array of selected items, but only supports storing strings in the array. I use a custom binding that supports storing objects in the array (like `selectedOptions` does):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.checkedInArray = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "click", function() {
            var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                array = options.array, // don't unwrap array because we want to update the observable array itself
                value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.value),
                checked = element.checked;
            ko.utils.addOrRemoveItem(array, value, checked);
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            array = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.array),
            value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.value);

        element.checked = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(array, value) >= 0;
    }
};
```

The binding for each checkbox then looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedInArray: { array: $parent.selectedItems, value: $data }" />
```

The checkbox for selecting all items uses the normal `checked` binding and is attached to a writable computed observable:

```
this.allItemsSelected = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return this.selectedItems().length === this.items().length;
    },
    write: function(value) {
        this.selectedItems(value ? this.items.slice(0) : [] );
    },
    owner: this
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/L3LeD/

**Update:** Knockout 3.0.0 introduced the `checkedValue` binding option that makes the above custom binding unnecessary. You can now bind the checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedItems, checkedValue: $data" />
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/RLLX6/

Comment: Brilliant! Had to modify my code to work with the selectedItems array instead, but actually ended up with less code, and unchecking now is as fast as checking.

Comment: I'm using this in a paging scenario, however it doesn't seem to preserve the checkboxes that have been checked between pages.  Should this automatically work or do I have to add in code of my own?

Comment: @DotNetHaggis, perhaps this can help you: http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/06/knockout-debugging-strategies-plugin.html

Comment: It's all good @MichaelBest I managed to work it out.  It won't work with your code I'm afraid... or didn't in my case.

Answer (score 0):

What happens to performance if you use jQuery to check/uncheck all the boxes?

```
$('#tableId').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', checked);
```

Alternatively, could you check all the boxes when you display them, rather than doing all of them in one go?

Also, you could try using the [knockout.utils](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) methods for filtering the observable arrays, I'd be interested to see if there's any performance difference there.

```
var filteredArray = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
        return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.name().toLowerCase(), filter);
    });
```

There is also a method for looping over an array and processing each element:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items(), function(item) {
    var value = parseFloat(item.priceWithTax());
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
        total += value;
    }
});
```

Again, I have no idea if this will help with performance or not, though I think it's a bit better prettiness-wise!

Comment: Using jQuery would be hard, as i only display 50 items at a time, I still have to keep track of all checked though, when posting, which is why I am using ko to check.

I will give the ko filtering a go, didnt know about that one, gonna see if it helps

Comment: I have tried the arrayfilter, instead of jQuery grep, which didnt make any difference. 

I also originally used the arrayForEach, but changed to regular for loop, just to check as well. So far, the only impact on performance, has been when i removed observables that wasnt nescessary.

Still wondering why its only on uncheck though, not check....

Comment: Can you put together a jsFiddle to give us something to tinker with? I'm also curious as to why this only happens on uncheck. Have you used a profiler to dig into where the most time is spent?

Comment: I have created a jsFiddle, but im struggling to make it slow, so I will try and dumb down my own code, untill i find whats actually slowing it down. http://jsfiddle.net/x3cnV/32/