# Knockout: How to use checked binding with observable array of whole objects, but compare individual properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mvvm, knockout.js, observable

My problem is as follows: I am trying to use a checkbox binding to bind an array of objects to a list of selected objects. My problem is, I would like to bind the entire object to the list, as follows:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedItems, value: $data">
    </div>
</div>
```

Where *items* is the list of objects to be bound to the *selectedItems* observable array.

However, to check if the value is "checked", I would like to compare individual object properties. The reason for this is that I am gathering objects from different sources, and some represent the same object, but they are not entirely identical. Furthermore, I need to use certain sub-properties of the selected objects in other functions, so I need the entire object to be bound to the observable array.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Although the built-in binding won't allow you to do this, as shown by Jonathan in his answer, you can do this with a custom binding. A starting point could be here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15215412/1287183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig into the knockout api you can see then when the 'checked' parameter is an array, the binding handler determines if the value is in the array as such:

```
element.checked = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(modelValue, checkedValue()) >= 0;
```

Typically checkedValue() will be set to the item in the options, having the same value as '$data':

```
var list = ko.observableArray({ value: "One" }, { value: "Two" });
var objectsInList = ko.observableArray(list[0]);
```

In an options binding like this, in which checkedValue is not specified, the value of $data will be the object:

```
<select data-bind="options: list, checked: objectsInList">
```

I didn't specify checkedValue, and therefore in the checked binding handler it will do the arrayIndexOf() operation based on object reference.

What you want to do is specified in the knockout documentation:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

You can set checkedValue in the data-bind parameters like this:

```
var list = ko.observableArray({ value: "One" }, { value: "Two" });
var objectsInList = ko.observableArray("One");

<select data-bind="options: list, checked: objectsInList, checkedValue: 'value'">
```

If you want to handle multiple object parameters I think you would need to write your own binding handler.

Comment: I wound up looking into most of this on my own, but at least your answer is accurate and you've done your best to answer the question fully. Thanks for the well thought out response!

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions in bindings.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked($data), ...">
```

Just keep in mind bindings wrap your code into computed and that's how you get auto ui refresh. This means Knockout may not update ui when you expect it too.

But, really, you need to have consistent data in your view model.

Comment: I agree, but whereas I'm not the one making the webservices, I can't really enforce that.. I just have to work with what they give me

Comment: @user3645275 you always can process data from WebService and create consistent model before binding them

Comment: Not really.. In my case the new information returned at a later time is still relevant (even though it differs from the old object)

Comment: Also, it's returned in unknown quantities, so it may cause unnecessary memory usage and also slow the program down quite a bit..

Comment: @user3645275 then you have щтдн two options: 1. wrap your data and add minimal api such as `isChecked`; or 2. use separate set of functions in bindings

Comment: Yes, I decided on the former a little while ago

Answer (score 0):

change your html to

```
data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'item'}">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: item.checked, value: item.value">
  </div>
</div>
```

Structure your items as

```
this.items = ko.observableArray([
    {checked: true1, value : value1},
    {checked: true2, value : value2},
    {checked: true3, value : value3},
])
```

Of course in real life you don't have variables called true1, value1 etc, that would be json data returned from an API

Note: to avoid problems with `this` you probably want at the start of your viewModel

```
`var self = this`
```

and use

```
`self.items = `
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the checked binding that links to an observable array, though. This is shown in the second example here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html. I need the array to speed up/simplify subsequent processes

Comment: I think you need to share your viewModel - or at least the relevant parts. In general, your "checked" property should be calculated in the viewModel or set via an observable.  You can always use $index to link into an array if the properties are in the same order as the items