# Knockout - Checking checkboxes according to observableArray

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, checkbox, knockout.js

So I have a list of schedules that I need to display for a user and show which schedules he or she is currently on and give them the possibility to jump on and off said schedules.

My viewmodel looks like this

```
self = this;
self.shifts = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedShifts = ko.observableArray();

//I populate self.shifts here with a WEB API call

//Run through each shift and check if current user is on it and set checked / not checked    value for checkbox
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.shifts(), function(shift) {

           //Clear array
            self.usersOnShift([]);

            //Populate array with all users on the shift
            self.usersOnShift = ko.observableArray(WEB API CALL HERE);

            var userInShift = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.usersOnShift(), function(user) {
                if (selectedUserId == user.ID) {
                    return true;
                } 
            });

            if (userInShift) {

                self.selectedShifts.push(shift.ID);
            }
        });

ko.applyBindings(self);
```

My HTML looks like this

```
  <div class="simple_overlay" id="shiftOverlay">
        <div class="details">

            <div data-bind="foreach: shifts">

                <div><span class="staff-initials" data-bind="text:wardName">  </span><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: ID, checked: $root.selectedShifts"/>  </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#" data-bind="click: updateUserOnShifts">Connect</a>
                <a href="#" data-bind="click: closeShiftDialog">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I can see that the value of the checkboxes are set correctly to the ID of the corresponding shifts. However a shift that I know the user in question is on is not checked and I know that the selectedShifts observableArray contains the value.

Somehow the "checked: $root.selectedShifts" call / check is not working but I know that it contains the right value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `shift.ID` a string or a number?

Comment: It seems strange that `usersOnShift` is an observable and that it's part of the view-model since it's just needed within the loop.

Comment: shift.ID is an integer.

True that usersOnShift needed not be part of the viewModel.

Couldn't issue be in the HTML where I reference the selectedShifts with the $root context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that your value is an integer, but when bound to the `checkbox` element, it becomes a string. When the `checked` binding tries to find the value in the array, it doesn't find a match because it uses strict equality for comparison and `(2 === "2")` is false.

The simplest way to work around this problem is to convert your values to string when you add them to the array:

```
self.selectedShifts.push("" + shift.ID);
```

Of course this means that your model has to change, and that might not be a great solution. I came up with a custom binding, `checkedInArray` that replaces `checked` and supports any type of value. You can [learn about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14863924/1287183), [see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/L3LeD/), and use it like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedInArray: {value: ID, array: $root.selectedShifts }" />
```

In Knockout 2.3.0 (which is still in development) there will be a new binding, [`checkedValue`](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/875), that will allow you use any type of value with the `checked` binding. Using that version, you could update your HTML to use `checkedValue`:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: ID, checked: $root.selectedShifts"/>
```

Comment: Hej Michael and thanks for your response. I tried the first approach and you were right in your thoughts. Converting the integer to a string made the comparison possible against the selectedShifts observableArray.

I will look into your custom binding and might write in this post again if I run in to trouble.

Thanks for your assistance and good weekend / Easter.

Answer (score 0):

Is shift.ID an observable property? If it is, then you need to add it to the array like this:

```
self.selectedShifts.push(shift.ID());
```

Otherwise you're just adding the whole observable to the array, and not the value.

Comment: shift.ID is just a normal property on the shift object.

If I alert out all values added to the self.selectedShifts I get a "2" which is the correct ID of the shift that the user is currently on.


`ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedShifts(), function(shift) {

               alert(shift);
            });`

Comment: If you put a break point in just before you applyBindings, what does selectedShifts look like?

Comment: It does not contain the shift in question, because the viewModel code from the first arrayForEach is inside a viewModel click event that is triggered when a link is pressed and an hidden overlay is displayed. That is when I know which user that is clicked and i can determine which shifts he is on and off.