# Creating A generic isselected solution

Tags: knockout.js

I have an interesting dilemma to which I didn't find a solution yet...  Hope someone can point me into the right direction.

I'm working with knockout / MVVM and I was kinda fed up of making ajax request about anywhere in my solution for the same data...  So I decided to create a small library to load and manage the common data and start using it from there.  This works and it's fine.

Based on this, i have a lot of views where i would need to be able to select multiple options and have the server notify of them.  i've written some logic to do this, and in essence this works to fine now through checkboxes  and checked and having iselected on the object , ... and when finished looping through the array , checking the isselected and returning a new array with the id's of the selected objects...

here's the thing, although, this works fine.  i have to do it per entity over and over again... so, in my optimizing mood i thought...

instead of having (e.g.):

- Country ((base function/object with the definition for Language + isselected)
- CountryList (containing the array and the logic to return the selected id's)
- Language (base function/object with the definition for Language + isselected)
- LanguageList ((containing the array and the logic to return the selected id's)
- .....

I thought I could try to make a generic solution like... 
  * Base function/object ( could be anything (generic) : country, language, ...)
  * Selector Function (which holds an array of Base objects with addition isselected on it)

so i could do something like: 
  incoming JSON -> foreach create BASE objects and put into BASE array

CreateObservableArrayFunction (Base array) which adds isselected logic and can return the id() of any generic object as long as they have the id() property.

it should be also possible to use this function to use it in the MVC views itself...

A note... the same could be used also for filtering etc.

Maybe a explained it badly, but i think this could be useful for other too instead of having to duplicate code all the time.

Thanks for your comments.

J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `checked` binding can also work with an array and will then add/remove the current item from that array.

For your "country" example, you'd use it something like this. View model:

```
...
vm.CountryList = ko.observableArray(); // list of countries
vm.CountrySelectedIds = ko.observableArray(); // list of country ids 
...
```

Template:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: CountryList">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="
        attr: {value: Id}, 
        checked: $parent.CountrySelectedIds" />
</div>
```

This works well if your "Id" is a string. If you want to store something other than strings (for example, the `Country` object itself), check out my [`checkedInArray` binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14863924/1287183).