# Performance Knockout Tip for updating lot of observables at once

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using this computed, and as you can imagine, when i click on selectAll, all checkbox got selected (one by one) and I 'think' can be a optimized so all get checked and then re-evaluate the model but i'm not sure it's possible.

```
self.selectAllExpired = ko.computed({
                    read: function() {
                        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.paymentOrdersExpired(), function(order) {
                            return !order.isSelected();
                        }) == null;
                    },
                    write: function(value) {
                        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.paymentOrdersExpired(), function(order) {
                            order.isSelected(value);
                        });
                    },
                    owner:this
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throttling would be a good choice for this type of scenario:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html

Even using `.extend({ throttle: 1 })` added to your computed, will prevent the computed from triggering multiple updates while you are checking each box.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm that I use to avoid rechecking the whole array when an item's selection changes:

```
function getIsAllSelectedComputed(arrayObservable) {
    var unSelectedCount = ko.observable(), arrayVersion = 0;
    function updateSelectedCheck(arrayValue) {
        ++arrayVersion; // Whenever the array changes, increment the version
        var initialUnSelectedCount = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(arrayValue, function(item) {
            var previousValue = item.isSelected();
            if (!previousValue)
                initialUnSelectedCount++;
            if (!item._isSelectedSubVersion) {
                item.isSelected.subscribe(function(latestValue) {
                    if (item._isSelectedSubVersion === arrayVersion) {
                        // Only update the unSelectedCount if the "truthiness" has changed
                        if (Boolean(previousValue) ^ Boolean(latestValue))
                            unSelectedCount(unSelectedCount() + (latestValue ? -1 : 1));
                        previousValue = latestValue;
                    }
                });
            }
            item._isSelectedSubVersion = arrayVersion;
        });
        unSelectedCount(initialUnSelectedCount);
    }
    updateSelectedCheck(arrayObservable());
    arrayObservable.subscribe(updateSelectedCheck);

    return ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return (unSelectedCount() === 0);
        },
        write: function(value) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(arrayObservable(), function(item) {
                item.isSelected(value);
            });
        }
    });    
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/ssEqj/

Comment: For another solution, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14863924/1287183) that uses a `checkedInArray` binding.