# When checking every checkbox with script, Knockout model does not get updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a series of check boxes that are all bound to an array of selected values:

```
var myModel = {
   // ...
   workgroupsImpacted: ko.observableArray([])
};
```

At the top, I have a *Select All* check box.  When the *Select All* check box is selected, I run the following code:

```
var subGroups = $('#WorkgroupCB_' + parentId);
$(':input', subGroups).prop('checked', this.checked);
```

This checks (or unchecks) the corresponding checkbox controls.  This works great, UI wise, however the bound model does not get updated.  In other words, `workgroupsImpacted` remains empty.

Is there an easy way to update the model when I *check* or *uncheck* a bunch of check boxes?  Or, do I have to loop through each check box, dig up the value, and manually add or remove that value from the array in my model?  I'm hoping Knockout.js provides a standard mechanism for doing this easily.

Comment: If you check one of the individual checkboxes, does `workgroupsImpacted` get updated? If so, how does this happen?

Comment: @MichaelBest - Yes, each individual checkbox is bound to the `workgroupsImpacted` array.  However, the checkboxes are rendered on the server rather than using a `foreach` template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `KnockoutJS`, the `observable array` just keeps track of the amount of items in the array and reports changes (i.e. adding/removing items), but it does not keep track of the state of the objects within that array.

It sounds like you want to have an `observable array` of `observables`. Do you have a model object that represents each `checkbox` in the list?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hee4g/2/) that shows the tracking of checkboxes within an `observable array`.

Comment: Thanks!  I think the answer is basically that I need to update the model, not the DOM; which is what I suspected.  The issue is that the check boxes come from the database (and are rendered as HTML) and are actually more of a check box *tree*.  I want to check a parent node and have all the leaf nodes be selected.  Trying to build a model with that hierarchy of check boxes would be rather complicated, as that information is not known by the client.  I would probably have to parse the DOM and build a JSON representation, or query the server via AJAX; neither which I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use jquery to do that.

You should just have a model representing the checkbox, containing a ko.observable representing the state of the checkbox. to check everything, you would just have to loop over the checkboxes and change the ko.observable to true.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a writable computed observable to represent your "check all" checkbox. Here's an example:

```
this.allItemsSelected = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return this.selectedItems().length === this.items().length;
    },
    write: function(value) {
        this.selectedItems(value ? this.items.slice(0) : [] );
    },
    owner: this
});
```

I've written [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14863924/1287183) to a similar question that goes into more detail on the above example including this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/L3LeD/

In the write function, if you want to populate your selected items array with a property of each item, you can use this:

```
this.selectedItems(value ?
    ko.utils.arrayMap(this.items(), function(item) { return item.property; }) :
    [] );
```

Comment: This would be tough since I have an indeterminate number of "check all" check boxes.  I'd have to parse the DOM then build the model from that, which I find somewhat convoluted.

Comment: Okay. That's a strange situation. Knockout assumes that the DOM is dependent on the model, not the other way around. Maybe you just need to use something other than Knockout (like plain jQuery).

Comment: Well, I could probably do an AJAX query to load all that UI data from the server once the page loads.  Then, create my model from there which would in turn create the DOM.  I decided against this because creating the checkboxes was easy using an ASP.NET Repeater control.

Comment: I added another answer that I think applies to your situation better.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you don't want to have to maintain the list of items in your model. It's still possible to work with this situation in Knockout and the method is to use a custom binding.

Here's one I've put together that will update the checkboxes using `click` (because that's what Knockout watches for). To make sure the "check all" checkbox is up-to-date, it watches for changes to the array (simply by accessing it within the `update` function) and then just looks for any unchecked checkboxes.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.allChecked = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).click(function() {
            $(valueAccessor().selector)
                .filter(element.checked ? ':not(:checked)' : ':checked')
                .click();
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            watch = ko.unwrap(value.watch),
            unchecked = $(value.selector).filter(':not(:checked)');
        element.checked = (unchecked.length === 0);
    }
};
```

Bind it to a checkbox input element like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="
    allChecked: {
        selector: '#checks input:checkbox', 
        watch: selectedItems}" />
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/nth7A/